# FFMpeg switch between live stream and a text video when streaming to YouTube

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, youtube

I have been running a Youtube livestream for a while and I am developing a solution so that I can run the stream remotely through a browser. My plan is to have an ASP.net core web api project running a background service that when I send the streaming information to it, it launches FFMpeg to stream a USB webcam. I also need to be able to press a button to "mute" the stream so it shows a blank video with some text overlay (i.e. "Technical Difficulties").

My solution so far is to use two instances of FFMpeg. When I switch modes, I kill one process and start the other one. I have gotten it working somewhat, but when I switch back and forth between "mute mode" and "streaming mode", Youtube seems to choke on the stream being changed. I suspect it's because when I go from mute mode back to stream mode, youtube doesn't recognize that the mute mode has ended. Also, mute mode displays the text like I want, but it causes the Youtube player to stop being "live" so that if I do get the regular stream going again, the user has to click the "Live" button to be up to date.

Here's the command line for both modes:

*Stream Mode:*

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i video="<webcam name>" -f dshow -i audio="<microphone name>" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 3500k -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<stream key>
```

*Mute Mode (blank.mp4 is a 3 second long blank video):*

```
ffmpeg.exe -stream_loop -1 -i ./FFMpeg/blankvid.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:text='Technical Difficulties':fontcolor=white:fontsize=60:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 3500k -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<stream key>
```

Last note: I know that there may be a way using a color filter to create the black video, rather than having a blankvid.mp4. If you also know how to get the parameters for that, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot more searching and trial and error, I seem to have it working now. Not sure if all the parameters are necessary but the problem was with the "Mute" command. I also figured out how to use the color filter instead of a blank video. I ended up changing it to

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -f lavfi -i "color=black:s=1280x720" -f lavfi -i anullsrc -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 3500k -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:text='Technical Difficulties':fontcolor=white:fontsize=60:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<stream key>
```